# Making combos with keyboard and detecting the most precise

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

On the `window` I bind two `keydown` events. The condition for triggering a callback function is a certain sequence:

```
Event #1: ["down", "right", "a"]
Event #2: ["down", "right", "down", "right", "a"]
```

How can I check if the user pressed the event 2 keys and then cancel the event 1?

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/5xGa6/), focus on the red div and press the keys <kbd>▼</kbd> <kbd>►</kbd> <kbd>▼</kbd> <kbd>►</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, you will see the two events triggering. I need to know how can I check if a more precise one have been triggered...

To check if the sequence is right I compare the sequence with the end of the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more precise one, is the one with more keys. Alter your code so it only `$(window).kb` once, and to register a sequence, one calls another function that will fill an array structure similar to this:

```
[
 {
    seq:["down", "right", "down", "right", "a"],
    callback: cb1
 },
 {
    seq:["down", "right", "a"],
    callback: cb2
 }
]
```

the registration function will insert any new element in this array according to it's `seq.length`, so this array will always be sorted more precise to less precise.

Now your only `$(window).kb`, will each time loop this array looking for a match, once found, it will call the corresponding `callback` and stop iterating the array.

Comment: Your hint was helpful. Here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/5xGa6/1/ . Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Np :) I've optimized the code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662633/how-can-i-optimize-this-code) and now this might be the final version http://jsfiddle.net/eQUhr/